# How to retrieve characters from string with help of LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net

I have string:

```
string str = "GoodDay";
```

I need to retrieve the first three characters with the help of LINQ.

Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: You don't need linq for that...

Comment: Just curious, why Linq for this basic task?

Comment: @Steve it's often asked on interviews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String is `IEnumerable<char>` so you can query it. Use `Enumerable.Take` method:

```
IEnumerable<char> firstThreeChars = str.Take(3);
```

If it's not required for you to use LINQ, then better option is usage of `str.Substring(0,3)` - that will return substring containing first three characters.

Answer (score 6):

If you must use LINQ, you can do this:

```
foreach ( char c  in str.Take(3)) {
    ...
}
```

However, with strings it is much more conventional to use `Substring`s:

```
foreach (char c in str.Substring(0, 3)) {
    ...
}
```